# IBOutlet and IBAction get disabled when VC is linked to TabBarController

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am trying to add a IBOutlet connection from a UIView to a ViewController.swift file and when I add the Tab Bar Controller to the storyboard the functionality to add the IBOutlet does not appear when I hover over the location to add the IBOutlet.

My tests:
**Test 1:**
I can add an IBOutlet to a UIview from a new project if I have not tried to add the Tab Bar Controller to the storyboard previously.

If I add the tab bar controller after I link an IBOulet to the storyboard, the IBOulet works and I can add additional IBOutlets.

Although I could use this to solve my problem, I would rather not start my project over.

**Test 2:**
If I add the Tab Bar Controller first in a test project I can't add an IBOutlet to a UIView.

If I delete the Tab Bar Controller, I still can't add an IBOutlet to the UIView

Question:
How do I get the functionality to add IBOutlets to a UIView when I have already added a Tab Bar Controller?

Is there something that is getting disabled that I can turn on when a Tab bar controller is added? Or is there something I can do programmatically to fix the problem?

The picture shows the UIview and the Tab Bar Controller. This scenario is the test 2 scenario where I added a Tab Bar Controller and then tried to link an IBOutled to the ViewController, which doesn't work.

I am using Xcode 10.1

Comment: I can't seem to find the picture you're talking about.

Answer (score 0):

Go into the identity inspector and make sure the storyboard view is connected to the ViewController